# Complete list of .NET conversion operators

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#

Does anyone have a complete list of the conversion operators for VB/C# and how they differ?

So far I know about...

- value as type [C#]
- TryCast(value, type) [VB]
- Convert.ToXxx(value) [any]
- (type)value [C#]
- CType(value, type) [VB]
- DirectCast(value, type) [VB]
- CXxx(value) [VB]
- CTypeDynamic [any]
- implicit conversions when using Option Strict Off [VB]
- implicit conversions when using dynamic [C#]
- type value [F#]
- :> [F#]
- :?> [F#]

But of course just having the list isn't the same as knowing the subtle differences between each one.

Comment: (I'm looking forward to the grumpy article about how complicated type conversions are in all the various .NET languages.  :)  )

Comment: Are you also interested in implicit conversions (e.g. lambda-to-delegate)?

Comment: @Adam, I forgot how to do that.

Comment: @Brain, yes, I think that would be important.

Comment: let's not forget C# dynamic related assignment conversion

Comment: @Jonathan: Edit your question and click the checkbox.

Comment: Here's some info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Answer (score 4):

For F# versus C# on casts/conversions, see

[What does this C# code look like in F#? (part one: expressions and statements)](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry)

for a short discussion of numeric conversions, boxing conversions, upcasts, and downcasts.

(Note that you list

```
type value
```

for F#, I presume you're talking about e.g.

```
int 'a'
```

but note that `int` here is the name of a *function* in the F# library, rather than the name of a *type*.  See the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754.aspx); in general there is a function named `T` for each primitive numeric type `T`, and that function converts its argument to the destination type of the same name.)

Regarding *implicit* conversions in F#:

- There's **`string` -> `PrintfFormat`** (as part of the magic for typesafe `printf`)
- There's **upcasts** at method calls arguments and property/array assignments that enables you to do e.g. `f(dog)` or `person.Pet <- dog` when an `Animal` is expected.  This also works for known nominal types for collection literals, e.g. `let controls : Control list = [button; form; window]`
- There's a **function-to-delegate conversion** at method call arguments, which enable e.g. `new Thread(fun() -> ())` where the F# function is converted to the `ThreadStart` delegate.
- There's **`ref` to `byref` conversion** at method call arguments, which enables you to pass a `ref` to e.g. an `out` parameter.

I think those are it - there are very few implicit conversions in F#.

Comment: VB is similar in that most type casting operators are either library functions or could be changed into library functions. The only ones that are actual syntax are CType, TryCast, and DirectCast.